# Firefox Extension keeps running in background

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have created a Firefox extension, which has iframe in the popup.html.
To pass messages between iframe and main.js, I'm using postMessage method.

The popup is behaving weird when receiving message. I used console.log to get the message which is being received. The message gets console.log that many times, the times extension was clicked.
For e.g. if I had open the extension 4 times, the iframe passes the message only once, but the message gets receied 4 times.

To make you understand I'm writing step by step process:

1. Open a tab, and click on extension.
2. A message is passed from iframe to the main.js, which after receiving message, console.logs the same message. Now this message appears once.
3. Click anywhere to close extension. Click on extension again > message is passed > console.logs the same message twice.

Repeat this process, and it logs the message those many times, the extension is clicked.

Is this a bug with Firefox? Or I'm doing something wrong?
EDITED:
Here is some snippet from my main.js:

```
if (self.port !== undefined){  
  self.port.on("show", function(a,b) {  
    myApp.initialize(a,b);  
  });
}

var myApp = {
  initialize: function (a,b){
    window.addEventListener ("message" , receiveMessage, false);
    function receiveMessage(event){
      console.log("event.data - - - - - - ",event.data);
    }
  },
  goAbc : function(){
    self.port.emit("close");
  }
}
```

The code in iframe is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  parent.postMessage("getData", "*");
});
```

EDITED: One more question:
If I'm calling "myApp.goAbc()" somewhere in the code, it says, self.port is undefined. What's the issue here? Should I use something else in place of self.port?

Comment: Post a minimal reproduce example (code) please.

Comment: @nmaier :I have updated the question with the code. Pls have a look. :)

Comment: Ask new questions, don't use edit in addtional stuff. And still, if you want good answers (or answers at all) then you'll have to post a **complete**, reproducible example. There is no point in guessing where your `window` and/or `self` comes from.

Comment: @nmaier : Ok. Sure. M almost new to SO for asking questions, so m not that much perfect on how to post questions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each `"show"`, you call `myApp.initialize`, which `addEventListener` a new event listener. So the first time, there is one, the next time there will be another, additional one (as you call `addEventListener` again) for a total of two, and so on.

Instead, you need to call `addEventListener` exactly once and not on each `"show"`.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I got one more question, for that I'm editing the question again. Help, me in that also. Thanks :)